# Set folder view in OpenPictureDialog (in Delphi)

Tags: windows, delphi

I'm using **OpenPictureDialog** to allow the user to select an image stored locally.

When the dialog opens the **InitialDirectory** the view is whatever the user set for that folder or the default folder view.

How can I force the folder view to be "Large icons" or "Extra large icons"?

Comment: I tried the method outlined in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032421/setting-the-folder-view-in-a-cfiledialog-mfc), and it works on my machine. However, it apparently is undocumented.